# Why no tag for "The Fades"?

Tags: feature-request, tags

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [We need a Liaden tag](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1118/we-need-a-liaden-tag)

Shouldn't there be a [the-fades](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-fades) tag for the BBC's [*The Fades*](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/11657/2264)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's just not created yet, If you have a question, just leave it with a generic tag for now, flag it for moderator attention with the requested flag, and we can add it.